# Waiting for async taks in SQL Server Service Broker

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

I am learning SQL Server Service Broker as a tool to coordinate async tasks. Let's say I have a `MasterService` which combines data from `EmployeeInfoService` and `PayrollInfoService`. I get a list of `EmployeeIDs` then send each as a conversation to both services. At the end of those two services are activation sproc which will handle two `EmployeeIDs` at a time.

A couple questions

1. How can I store the responses for each employee into temp tables inside my `MasterService`?
2. How do I know that the two services have done processing all `EmployeeIDs` so I can generate data from the two temp tables I built in step #1?

Here's my code so far:

```
-- Get a whole bunch of EmployeeIDs

DECLARE @EmployeeConversation   uniqueidentifier
DECLARE @PayrollConversation    uniqueidentifier

BEGIN DIALOG @EmployeeConversation
    FROM SERVICE    MasterService
    TO SERVICE      'EmployeeInfoService';

    SEND ON CONVERSATION @EmployeeConversation MESSAGE (EmployeeID1)
    SEND ON CONVERSATION @EmployeeConversation MESSAGE (EmployeeID2)
    SEND ON CONVERSATION @EmployeeConversation MESSAGE (Employee...);

BEGIN DIALOG @PayrollConversation
    FROM SERVICE    MasterService
    TO SERVICE      'PayrollInfoService'
    WITH RELATED_CONVERSATION_GROUP = @EmployeeConversation;

    SEND ON CONVERSATION @PayrollConversation MESSAGE (EmployeeID1)
    SEND ON CONVERSATION @PayrollConversation MESSAGE (EmployeeID2)
    SEND ON CONVERSATION @PayrollConversation MESSAGE (Employee...);

-- Now I need to wait till both conversations are done.
-- How do I handle that?
```

Answer (score 3):

> Now I need to wait till both conversations are done.

No you don't. That is the most important part for message oriented programming: you never **wait** for a response. The response may come in a second, or it may come in a week. What you do is you finish processing, this is it, done. When the response comes from the service then you get activated and you process the response.

So in your case you associate a procedure with the `MasterService` queue:

```
create procedure usp_masterService
as
begin transaction
receive message_body, messge_type from MasterServiceQueue;
if message_type = 'EmployeeInfoMessage' then
   insert or update into stateTable info from message body;
if message_type = 'PayrollInfoMessgae' then
   insert or update into stateTable info from message body;
if allResponsesReceived
   do something
...
commit

alter queue MasterServiceQueue with activation (procedure usp_masterService);
```

How do you handle the state associated with employee info requests and how you detect 'all responses received' is entirely business logic. But you cannot use temp tables, the responses will be processed by various transactions on various threads (activated procs) and, most importantly, they may be processed *across a server restart*.

Your flow has to handle graciously the case when 'PayrollInfoService' is remote (on a different machine) and is undergoing a 6 hours maintenance right now. Your reponses will come, but will take 6 hours. How do you expose this in the application UI will depend from case to case. But think disconnected, loosely coupled, non-interactive services.